# getting all list data in the react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have rendered list-view with multiple text fields in react native ,I want to get all data that is filled in the list text fields on save button, can someone guide me on this?I'm new to react native.
adding screenshot of list-view below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data in the `state` as soon as `text` is changed in the `input` field. (`onChange` property of `input`)

`onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}`

Create a list in the state with key and value. `Key` represent index and `value` represents `text` (data) at that index of the list.

And on `button` click get the list from `state`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually I'm rendering row data using class and have form with multiple input types you can check image attached in the question, and save button is outside the list-view